Groovy: what is the Scope of timezone-change by the call of TimeZone.setDefault(...)
Description of existing environment:
There is a JIRA-cloud instance running worldwide on several nodes.
JIRA supports Groovy scripts.
One script being used to check and set values by certain custom-fields during creating of new JIRA-Issues and Issues-transition through JIRA-Workflow.
Some of affected custom fields are representing the datetime (e.g. "Due-Date", "Fixed on", etc.), correspondingly the script should be able to process them.
Inside the script - before the main operations being performed - the TimeZone being temporarily set to UTC (to get the "pre-defined" timezone & datetime-format):
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Note: the TimeZone being set not for logged-in user, but "in general" as described above.
Questions:

What is the scope of timezone-change by such call?
Could such call affect - how the JIRA-users are seeing the datetime values in JIRA?
If some not processed by the script JIRA-Issue being added or modified during the script has changed the TimeZone - will it affect the values of this Issue (e.g. when the script will turn timezone back to original value)?

The Groovy-documentation doesn't name the scope of the change.
The JAVA-documentation tells that the change affects "Java virtual machine".
How is it build by Groovy script running with JIRA-instance? Will it change the default TimeZone for the script-virtual-space only, or for all Groovy-scripts on this node, or also for the current node with JIRA-instance, or even for all nodes?
Update:
I found at least one reference, that the changing of Default-Timezone (also within JIRA-plugins) might have negative side-effects, see the Resolution part at following Atlassian page:
Incorrect timestamps displayed in Jira server
With assumption that Groovy is "well connected" with JIRA-system, I can imagine that changing of user-independent Default TimeZone within Groovy-script might cause such impact.

I suppose that‘s a call to Java. The call affects the JVM, so only has effect on the node in question. But yes, all users and all programs running in that JVM. So not really a good practice.

When a worldwide usage of Jira exists in a configuration, this kind of timezone configuration is acceptable and correct for a running script if you are somehow doing time calculations.
Think about it like that:

User A is in a place on UTC+3
User B is in a place on UTC+1

Let's say I want to send a mail to both users that the task will due on some due date, let's say today at 15:00 (UTC).
And let's assume that my Jira environment is on UTC+1.
If I directly say "This is ending on 15:00" without timezone, User A may miss this deadline if he/she thinks this is the local time.
So, I am getting the date like that, so that I can send the users to their local date.
Or, in another case, I may get some hour info from the user and he is entering it on his local time. So, I may want to convert that to UTC (or any desired time zone) to generalize this process.
There are bunch of variations of use cases, I just pointed two of them.
So, if you get the idea behind this approach, let's answer your questions:

This timezone change affects the process only. You are running the Groovy code and it is a process, and the timezone for this process is that value. So, if you use any date operation without saying timezone, the default will be UTC.
No. Because Jira has some general time zone info (you can check System Information tab on Advanced Settings) and the users are seeing the time depend on this time zone. Groovy scripts has no effect on that.
No, depend on the details of script. Let's say my time zone in Jira is UTC+1. I got the time as 13:00 on UTC+1. It means it is 12:00 UTC. I added 2 hours to that operated time, it is 14:00 UTC. When I update it on Jira, if I do the operation with current timezone info (UTC), no problem, it will be 15:00 UTC+1, which is correct.


I understand it so: JIRA server has "internal" TimeZone used by saving datetime-values (not sure if same over nodes, or each node has "own" one and re-calculates by data-exchange). User has own TimeZone-config.,which might even differ from user physical-location. On user-level it's clear: existing values being re-calc. to display in user-specific TimeZone. When user sets a value - it being stored by JIRA with recalculation to JIRA "internal" TimeZone based on user-config. Is a side-effect possible if script calls setDefault(), user creates an Issue (ignored by script), script reverts TimeZone?
